# Pandas Dataframe how to iterate over rows and perform calculations on their values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've started to work with Pandas Dataframe and try to figure out how to deal with the below task.
I have an excel spreadsheet that needs to be imported to Pandas DataFrame and the below calculations need to be done to populate PercentageOnSale , Bonus and EmployeesIncome columns.
If the sum of all SalesValues for the EmployeeID is less than 5000 the PercentageOnSale should be 5% of SalesValue.
If the sum of all SalesValues for the EmployeeID is equal or more than 5000 the PercentageOnSale should be 7% of SalesValue.
If the sum of all SalesValues for the EmployeeID is  more than 10.000 the PercentageOnSale should be 7% of SalesValue and additionaly a Bonus of 3% should be calculated.
EmployeesIncome is the sum of PercentageOnSale and Bonus columns.
[sample excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n14gk.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to make it easier for the community members to be able to help you, it is recommened that you follow the guidelines of questioning as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
Also please add any code which you have already tried.

Comment: I didn't add any code as I'm stuck just after importing my excel line.

Comment: I'll try to put it another way. I need to sum up values in column C for the same employeeID in column A and depending on this total value I need to perform calculations and imput the values in columns D,Eand F.

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) the many types of pandas calculations and aggregations, make an attempt from docs/searched answers, and return with **specific** issues that included reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `groupby-apply` as follows:

```
# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"EmployeeID":[1,1,2,3,1,3,5,1],
                   "ProductSold":["P1","P2","P3","P1","P2","P3","P1","P2"],
                   "SalesValue":[3000,3500,4000,3000,5000,3000,3000,4000]})

# Calculations
def calculate(x):
    # Calcualte Bonus
    x['Bonus'] = 0
    if x['SalesValue'].sum() > 10000:
        x['Bonus'] = 0.03*x['SalesValue']

    # Calculate PercentageOnSale
    if x['SalesValue'].sum() < 3000:
        x['PercentageOnSale'] = 0.05*x['SalesValue']
    else:
        x['PercentageOnSale'] = 0.07*x['SalesValue']

    # Total Income per sale
    x['EmployeesIncome'] = x['PercentageOnSale'] + x['Bonus']

    return x    

df_final = df.groupby('EmployeeID').apply(calculate)
```

The output is as follows:

```
      EmployeeID ProductSold  SalesValue  Bonus  PercentageOnSale  EmployeesIncome
0           1          P1        3000   90.0             210.0            300.0
1           1          P2        3500  105.0             245.0            350.0
2           2          P3        4000    0.0             280.0            280.0
3           3          P1        3000    0.0             210.0            210.0
4           1          P2        5000  150.0             350.0            500.0
5           3          P3        3000    0.0             210.0            210.0
6           5          P1        3000    0.0             210.0            210.0
7           1          P2        4000  120.0             280.0            400.0
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, it helps a lot :)